# Upgrading GWT version 2.7.0 to 2.10.0 causes issues

Tags: java, maven, gwt, dagger

After upgrading gwt to `2.10.0` and upgrading `mvn.compiler.version` to `1.8.0` from `1.7.0` following errors are occuring:

1. On testing phase

```
log4j:WARN Error during default initialization
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
```

2. When compiling tomcat:

```
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Error constructing Java AST
...
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.binding()Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/MethodBinding;
...
[INFO][ERROR] at xxx.java(241): GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

The gwt compiler caches certain things.  Could some things be hanging around from your 2.7 build?

Do a clean build, to remove the `/gwt-unitCache` folder.

Also in the temporary directory (on Linux `/tmp`) check for `gwt*` folders and delete them all.